# MYSQL triggers throws explicit or implicit commit is not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a simple MYSQL trigger which updates the auto increment to 0 when if no rows are present in the table after delete

Schema name - grid_prod
Table Name - q_triggers
Action - after delete

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `grid_prod`.`q_triggers_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `q_triggers` FOR EACH ROW
declare cnt INT;
BEGIN
set cnt = (select count(*) from q_triggers);
if cnt = 0
then
alter table q_triggers auto_increment = 1;
end if;
END
```

I get this error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>   ERROR 1422: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Comment: Do you really think that it will be  ``` ALTER TABLE ``` used if cnt=0 ?

Comment: Why do you want to reset the counter? What's the problem you try to solve with this?

Comment: @stickybit I'm working on an IOT application where the data I'm sending to the MCU based node cannot be more than 120bytes. If I dont reset the counter the sno is going to get bigger than that and my node is going to crash.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed do you have anything to add? TIA

Comment: The commit referred to is the ALTER table statement and there is not way round this in a trigger. You need a different approach and it would help if you tell us what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: Most `DDL` statement such as `ALTER TABLE` cause an implicit `COMMIT` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)). So you can't use them in a trigger as any operations performed in a trigger need to be able to be rolled back with the rest of the transaction if a `ROLLBACK` happens.

Comment: @RaghavGautam: I don't get that. A "normal" integer (i.e. no arbitrary precision version of it) has a fixed length, commonly four for example, regardless of the value. So an integer will always take the same space form your 120 Byte if you reset the counter or not.

Comment: So that means its better if perform these checks in my server application instead of mysql triggers?

Comment: Instead of doing all this stuff you can create procedure to truncate the table

Comment: @stickybit data being sent over to the node is in string. So this int along with with other data would be casted and then sent

Comment: Any chance to fix that?

Comment: @KedarLimaye running stored proc from a trigger again would be an implicit commit, right? 
That should again give the same error

Comment: @stickybit not possible in MQTT

Comment: My point is use procedure instead of trigger

Comment: @KedarLimaye and from where do you want me to call the proc?
application or trigger?

Comment: Thanks guys for you responses. I have figured out a way by changing the schema a bit and now I wont ever need to alter auto increment.